# TypeError: calendar.getName is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script

Why do I try to use `getname()`, the console gives me an error?

```
var cList = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
for (calendar in cList) {
  calendarList.push(calendar.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a bit of an issue using the [for...in loop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp).

In the snippet shared, `calendar` is just an index (number) and accordingly, you could make use of something like this —

```
function myFunction() {
  var cList = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var calendarList = [];
  for (calendar in cList) {
    calendarList.push(cList[calendar].getName());
  }
  console.log(calendarList);
}
```

Comment: Right, I confused it with for of